# How to insert a new row into a database and obtain the primary key as a result

Tags: postgresql, playframework, playframework-2.0, postgresql-9.1, anorm

I'm using Play2 with Anorm. Is there a way to execute an INSERT statement and obtain the automatically generated primary key as a result?

Comment: The raw PostgreSQL way to do this is via an `INSERT ... RETURNING` statement. Via JDBC you should be able to use JDBC's support for getting generated keys. With Play ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`RETURNING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html):

```
INSERT INTO tbl(foo)
VALUES ('bar')
RETURNING foo_id;
```

With [Anorm](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala/blob/master/documentation/manual/anorm.textile) it could look like this (I am not an expert with Anorm):

```
import play.db.anorm._

val firstRow = SQL("INSERT INTO tbl(foo)
                    VALUES ('bar') RETURNING foo_id").apply().head

val foo_id = firstRow[int](“foo_id”)
```

Comment: Yup, I ended doing something like this:

    SQL("INSERT INTO tbl(foo)
    VALUES ('bar') RETURNING foo_id").as(scalar[Long].single)